# F# 9 names into disjointed groups of 2, 3 and 4

Tags: list, f#

I am very new to F# and have been looking at and running examples of simple problems I've found online. I stumbled on one that does not seem to work though and I was hoping someone could explain what is happening in this code and why. The functions should return the 1260 different options in lists, but instead it returns the empty list []

```
let rec group ns xs =
    let rec combination n xs =
        match n, xs with
        | 0, xs -> [([], xs)]
        | _, [] -> []
        | n, x::xs -> 
            let ts = [for ys, zs in combination(n-1) xs do yield (x::ys, zs)]
            let ds = [for ys, zs in combination n xs  do yield (ys, x::zs)]
            ts @ ds
    match ns, xs with
    | [], _ -> ([])
    | n::ns, xs -> 
        [for g, rs in combination n xs do 
            for gs in group ns xs do
               yield g::gs]


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let list = ["One"; "Two"; "Three"; "Four"; "Five"; "Six"; "Seven"; "Eight"; "Nine"]
    let groupSizes = [2;3;4]

    printfn "%A" <| group groupSizes list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the second `for` it seems you're using a loop and recursion at the same time.

If you want to use recursion then you don't need to loop, recursion will loop for you, try changing the last lines to this:

```
| n::ns, xs -> 
    [for g, rs in combination n xs do 
        yield g
     yield! group ns xs]
```

Here `yield!` is equivalent to the `::` operation, I mean you can also write it like this:

```
    [for g, rs in combination n xs do yield g] :: group ns xs
```

Note, that `rs`is not used, so you can write `_` :

```
    [for g, _ in combination n xs do yield g] :: group ns xs
```

Finally note you can use a `map` instead, with the function `fst` :

```
    List.map fst (combination n xs do yield g) :: group ns xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo's answers should fix your recursion, however it's unclear if you are trying to practice recursion, F#, or combinatorics. So in case you do many similar problems, even to double-check the output you could just use a [combinatorics library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics) in .NET. For example:

```
#r @"..\packages\Combinatorics.1.0.3.2\lib\net40\Combinatorics.dll"

open Combinatorics.Collections

let list = ResizeArray["One"; "Two"; "Three"; "Four"; "Five"; "Six"; "Seven"; "Eight"; "Nine"]
let groupSizes = [2;3;4]

groupSizes 
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> Combinations<string>(list,x))
    |> Seq.toList
    //|> Seq.length
```

I made only one change, as the library expects Generic Collections, I used `ResizeArray`, which is just the usual C# List. `Seq.collect` will flatten the three collections into one, and at the end just use Seq.toList to manifest the result. The library also has Permutations and Variations, as well as an option to generate repetitions or not (seems that's the default).